# Simple Form Validation in Ruby not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, devise

I have a couple of forms in my `Ruby on Rails` project that all need validation. For one for, that creates users, the `f.error_notification` method works quite well for displaying errors, I believe because it's working with the user model. However I have another form for editing passwords that isn't working the right way. I'm trying to use all the same methods so that all of the error messages display the same everywhere on the website. The problem I'm having is that if the passwords don't match (or there's any other kind of problem), the `f.error_notification` displays in red at the top: `Please review the problems below.` As it should. But it doesn't actually display any problems below.

This is the form:

```
<h2>Change your password</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name),  :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>

  <div><%= f.label :password, "New password" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autofocus => true, required: true %></div><br />

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, required: true %></div>
  <br>
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn doc-action-btn btn-success") do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Change my password
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure what else to post code wise to help make this clearer but I'm happy to update my post if there's something else I can add. I should also note that the form above was generated by `Devise`. I switched from Devise error messages to the `Rails` ones for consistency's sake because we use the `Rails` ones elsewhere in our custom forms. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `devise_error_messages!` method. it is special devise method which take care of displaying errors. You can't flip back and forth unless you fully customise it.

if case you want to customize it, you can check this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Override-devise_error_messages!-for-views

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, in fact I replaced it with the `f.error_notification`, as I said, for consistency. Is there a way to customize the devise error messages so that they display beside each input instead of all up at the top?